# Can't start listener after recreating the listener

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-administration, oracle12c

i'm running oracle 12c in windows 2008 64 bit, recently I disabled the archive log and run oracle in noarchive log mood...

now i'm not able to start oracle listener and it gives me same Errol bellow all the time, here is complete logs.

```
<msg time='2016-10-13T15:02:45.182+04:30' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='oracleserver'
 host_addr='127.0.0.1'>
 <txt>Started with pid=5464
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2016-10-13T15:02:45.206+04:30' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='oracleserver'
 host_addr='127.0.0.1'>
 <txt>Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=oracleserver)(PORT=1536)))
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2016-10-13T15:02:45.311+04:30' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='oracleserver'
 host_addr='127.0.0.1'>
 <txt>Error listening on: (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PARTIAL=yes)(QUEUESIZE=1))
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2016-10-13T15:02:45.312+04:30' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='oracleserver'
 host_addr='127.0.0.1'>
 <txt>No longer listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=oracleserver)(PORT=1536)))
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2016-10-13T15:02:45.412+04:30' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='oracleserver'
 host_addr='127.0.0.1'>
 <txt>TNS-12532: TNS:invalid argument
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00502: Invalid argument
   64-bit Windows Error: 22: Invalid argument
 </txt>
</msg>
```

What I did:

- delete listener and recreate it manually.
- delete and recreate listener with netca
- change listener name to different one
- changed port number of listener
- add rules for inbound and outbound for the new port and old one

all those above I still get the same error, but my oracle starts normally without any issue I restart and start it multiple times.

here is **tnsnames.ora:**

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: c:\app\oracle\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENERORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1536))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 172.30.80.100)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

Here is **listener.ora**

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: c:\app\oracle\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = c:\app\oracle\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:c:\app\oracle\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr12.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENERORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = oracleserver)(PORT = 1536))
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENERORCL = c:\app\oracle\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\log
```

i'm just confused what is happening... another point when I delete and recreate listener with default port of 1521 it says the port is being used... this only happens when I create listener from netca...no matter what port I use it still complains about port being used but when I check with bellow:

netstat -aon :findstr :portnumber

it returns zero

thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: That's a bit more than turning off archive log mode.

Comment: well that is what I did now can't start listener...

Comment: Maybe change the title of the question to "Can't start listener after recreating the listener."

Comment: Are you sure your port 1536 is not being blocked by firewall?

Comment: Hello, yes i'm sure I created rule for it both in bound and outbound in windows firewall